# Installing azure-quantum with qiskit dependences

Tags: qiskit, programming, azure-quantum

I'm trying to install azure-quantum package with qiskit integration.

Following the azure tutorial (https://pypi.org/project/azure-quantum/) they say to use:

> pip install --upgrade azure-quantum[qiskit]

in an environment with python 3.9 or higher and pip v.19.2 or higher.

I'm trying to install azure-quantum[qiskit] in a Conda environment equipped with python 3.9.16 and pip 22.3.1.

However, installing just azure-quantum with:

> pip install --upgrade azure-quantum

works fine, while if I specify the qiskit tag I get:

> zsh: no matches found: azure-quantum[qiskit]

Any hint to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on macOS the default shell `zsh` treats `[` `]` as regex instead of a string. To workaround this you can either escape the `[` and `]` or put quotes around it. In other words do this instead:

```
pip install --upgrade "azure-quantum[qiskit]"
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade azure-quantum\[qiskit\]
```